# TestFlight showing my app size is 4 times less than the actual size

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I was really surprised to see my app size is 4 times less than the actual size. The application size is **32 MB** & I uploaded my app on TestFlight for beta app review , where TestFlight showing app is is only **8.5 MB** .
Can any one tell the reason behind it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually know why it is doing that but I also experienced that applications in TestFlight are extremely compressed so this is a normal thing.

I do think they might just download some files into the TestFlight app needed to run your app and load the code from the internet somewhere, can't explain another way this should work.

Hope it helps you :)