# Are testflight app sizes bloated by a large amount compared to actual download sizes after publishing?

Tags: ios, testflight, bitcode

I have built an iOS game with Unity. I uploaded it to the App Store (with bitcode enabled). **The IPA is about 200 mb.**

On iTunes Connect, it shows my build size to be about **30mb for each device** (which I was very happy to see).

But when I added the build to TestFlight, I notice that while downloading via TestFlight, it shows the size to be 170mb. Quite **contrary** to this question ([TestFlight showing my app size is 4 times less than the actual size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29271634/testflight-showing-my-app-size-is-4-times-less-than-the-actual-size)) the size of my app on TestFlight is many times the actual supposed sizes shown on iTunes Connect.

Also, iTunes Connect says:

```
TestFlight variants differ from store variants and have smaller sizes.
```

which is quite the opposite of what has happened. My TestFlight download is huge.

Is this normal?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

App size increase in Testflight is **common**, and is **completely normal**

- It includes Bitcode and code to analyse crashes. Once the app in in the app store it'll come back to normal size.
- You might also notice that for various screen sizes the size varies dramatically.

---

**How to check real App Store File Size :**

If you are worried about the size of your App Store file, you can check using below steps

- Go to `iTunes Connect` -> `Your App` -> `Activity` Tab

[image: screenshot 1]

- Go to the version you want to check and click on a build that you want to observe. There you have an option `App Store File Sizes`

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: thanks. even an increase from 30 mb to 170 mb is normal?

Comment: definitely. We had an app going 30mb - 97mb.

Comment: @batman refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/32588757/2538729 for more cases like yours. Incase you have any more doubts.

Comment: Most of the people there are saying TestFlight size = actual size. Some are saying TestFlight includes builds for all devices which makes it bigger. do you concur with the latter opinion?

all in all, are the sizes shown in iTunes Connect per device reliable ?

Comment: @batman I concur with the latter. I've personally saw the build size increase dramatically for testflight builds, where as itunes build was normal.

Comment: @batman I'm adding a screen shot where you can check app store sizes against a build