# After enabling Bitcode from project settings and uploading app to TestFlight, estimated App Store file size doubled. Is this normal?

Tags: ios, testflight, bitcode

I'm trying to reduce the size of my app, so first thing I wanted to try was enabling bitcode. I know the generated ipa size grows after enabling bitcode but I thought that the [estimated App Store size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37281103/1033616) would be significantly reduced. Apperantly it's doubled (at least its estimated size, I haven't released the app yet).

Here is the Estimated App Store file Size of my app with bitcode enabled on build settings and "upload bitcode" checkbox selected:

[image: Bitcode enabled]

Bitcode disabled:

[image: Bitcode disabled]

Is this normal? Shouldn't bitcode enabled build's size be something like 12-15 MB or at least lower than 24 MB?

Comment: Bitcode is an intermediate representation of a compiled program. Enabling it will increase the build (ipa) size on the developer front.

Comment: I know, ipa size is tripled and I don't mind it. But I didn't expect the "Estimated App Store file size" to be doubled. According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37281103/1033616) answer, the screenshots I posted represent actual App Store file sizes for each device.

Comment: When you submit an app (including Bitcode) Apple’s ‘BlackBox’ recompiles it for each supported platform and drops any ‘useless’ object code, so AppStore has a copy of the app for each CPU. When end user wants to install the app - He/She installs only version for particular processor, without any unused stuff. So you don't worry about it .