# App size shown in AppStore connect is 20 Mb less than TestFlight

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

The App size in **AppStore connect** is shown as **32.5 Mb** whereas in **TestFlight** it is showing **72.2 Mb** for the same device [iPhone 12]. This is happening after we recently upgraded the react native version of our application from 0.61 to 0.72.

Usually the app size is 72 Mb.

Want to know why this is happening? Or if I am missing something.

Saw these posts and I am confused if app size would be lesser in TestFlight than AppStore: [TestFlight showing my app size is 4 times less than the actual size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29271634/20201890), [Are testflight app sizes bloated by a large amount compared to actual download sizes after publishing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37280325/20201890)

[image: Size in AppStore connect]

[image: Size in TestFlight]